# Can't change the sender just before sending the email using FluentEmail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, mailkit

As the sender has limited emails to send per day or per hour, I need to select the proper sender according to the number of receivers, I am using FluentEmail Mailkit sender and trying to do something like that but still sending from the default sender configured in DI

```
fluentEmail.Sender = GetFluentEmailSender(fluentEmail.Sender, fluentEmail.Data.ToAddresses.Count);
```

**The DI configuration:**

```
services.AddFluentEmail(defaultFromEmail, defaultFromName).
                AddRazorRenderer(templateRootFolder);

services.AddSingleton<ISender>(new MailKitSender(
                new SmtpClientOptions
                {
                    Server = notificationSettings.EmailSettings.MailKitSender.Server,
                    Port = notificationSettings.EmailSettings.MailKitSender.Port,
                    Password = password,
                    UseSsl = notificationSettings.EmailSettings.MailKitSender.UseSsl,
                    User = notificationSettings.EmailSettings.MailKitSender.UserName,
                    SocketOptions = (MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions)notificationSettings.EmailSettings.MailKitSender.SocketOptions,
                    RequiresAuthentication = notificationSettings.EmailSettings.MailKitSender.RequiresAuthentication
                }

                ));
```

Is this a bug or am I misusing it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't know much about how an Asp.Net Core application is started. If you are interested, you can read the source code.

In short, the registration of services in the Startup file is performed only once, that's why you cannot modify the sender information in `services.AddSingleton<ISender>`.

---

If you want change the sender info, I suggest you can create `IEmailService`, and in this method we can read configuration from `appsettings.json` file. We just need to register this emialservice without any sender information.

***You can refer below blogs:***

[ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Send Emails via SMTP with MailKit](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/15/aspnet-core-3-send-emails-via-smtp-with-mailkit)